# Spring OAuth2: Why am I not getting back an access token from my request?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, access-token, spring-security-oauth2

I’m using Spring OAuth2 …

```
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

and I have set up the following authorization server (basically just ripped off the example online) …

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    private static final String ROLE1 = "ROLE1";
    private static final String ROLE2 = "ROLE2";
    private static final String ROLE3 = "ROLE3";

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "blog_resource";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    // [1]
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends
            AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        // [2]
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        // [3]
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
                throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory().withClient("client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities(ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3).scopes("read", "trust")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
                    .secret("secret123").and()
                    .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities(ROLE1, ROLE2, ROLE3).scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID).secret("secret");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }
}
```

My users are stored in a MySQL database.  However, when I run my app and visit

```
http://localhost:8080/my-context-path/oauth/token?client_id=my-client-with-secret&client_secret=secret&grant_type=password&username=ROLE3&password=password
```

I don’t get back an access token but rather receive

```
<oauth>
<script type="text/javascript">
window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }
</script>
<error_description>
Full authentication is required to access this resource
</error_description>
<error>unauthorized</error>
</oauth>
```

I have verified the un/pw are correct as well as the roles.  I figure I’m missing something real simple, but what is wrong with the URL or configuration that prevents my receiving an access token?

Comment: Are you putting in the correct headers? OAuth token requests are supposed to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: No, I wasn't doing that.  Thanks, -